# Magento after resizing product image, first time it doesn't show need to press ctrl+f5

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

After resizing product image, first time it doesn't show on product page. When I press (ctrl+f5) then it shows.

I have checked image is resizing and cached on server. Image is saving on static.domain.com

I have tried after clearing all cache also.

Comment: i am facing same issue, any solution yet?